# Using Comparator to sort array and keep index position

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

I'm trying to use Comparator to keep track of array value index's after sorting them. I've seen the implementation elsewhere, however I'm struggling to make it synergise with my code.

I've filled my 2d array with random values at [X][0] and [X][1] with my index values.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    public class ComparatorTest{

    static double testArray[][] = new double [10][10];

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            fillArray();
            setIndexVals();
        }

        public static void fillArray(){
            for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++){
                testArray[row][0] = Math.random();
                System.out.println(testArray[row][0]);
            }
        }

        public static void setIndexVals(){
            for (int row = 0; row < testArray.length; row++){
                testArray[row][1]= row + 1;
                System.out.println(testArray[row][1]);

            }
        }
        public static void sortArray(){
            Arrays.sort(testArray, new Comparator<int[]>(){
                public int compare(double[] value, double[] index){
                    return value[0]-index[0];
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you expect/want your program to do?

Comment: I want the values to be sorted in ascending order and for their original index values to be kept beside them.

Comment: Does the problem have to do with how you compared doubles like how I addressed it in my answer or is still not working?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public int compare(double[] value, double[] index){
    return value[0]-index[0];
}
```

with

```
public int compare(double[] value1, double[] value2){
    return Double.compare(value1[0], value2[0]);
}
```

I chose to rename the parameters in the `compare` method because it really takes in two arrays within the 2D array rather than a value and index array. If you want to compare indexes, then you would compare `value1[1]` and `value2[1]`.

But the real fix is changing `value[0]-index[0]` because you should rarely use exact comparisons to compare doubles.